# error : _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I was trying to make a catch the egg game but it didn't go to plan and it brought up an error saying

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas".
```

I have searched the whole of the internet about the problem but none of the solutions that people the person helped me at all.
anyways this is what I have written so far it would be appreciated if someone helped especailly because I'm new.

```
from itertools import cycle
from random import randrange
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk, messagebox, font

canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 400

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width = canvas_width, height = canvas_height, background="deep sky blue")
c.create_rectangle(-5, canvas_height - 100, canvas_width + 5, canvas_height + 5, fill = "sea green",  width=0)
c.create_oval(-80, -80, 120, 120, fill="orange", width=0)
c.pack()

color_cycle = cycle(["light blue", "light green", "light pink", "light yellow", "light cyan"])
egg_width = 45
egg_height = 55
egg_score = 10
egg_speed = 500
egg_interval = 4000
difficulty_factor = 0.95

catcher_color = "magenta"
catcher_width = 100
catcher_height = 100
catcher_start_x = canvas_width / 2 - catcher_width / 2
catcher_start_y = canvas_height - catcher_width - 20
catcher_start_x2 = catcher_start_x = catcher_width
catcher_start_y2 = catcher_start_y + catcher_height
catcher = c.create_arc(catcher_start_x, catcher_start_y, catcher_start_x2, catcher_start_y2, start = 200, extent = 140, \
                       style = "arc", outline = catcher_color, width = 3)

game_font = font.nametofont("TkFixedFont")
game_font.config(size = 18)
score = 0
score_text = c.create_text(10, 10, anchor="nw" , font=game_font, fill="darkblue", text="Score: " + str(score))

lives_remaining = 1
lives_text = c.create_text(canvas_width - 10, 10, anchor="ne", font = game_font, fill="darkblue", text = "Lives " + str(lives_remaining))

eggs = []
def create_egg():
    x = randrange(10, 740)
    y = 40
    new_egg = c.create_oval(x, y, x + egg_width, y + egg_height, fill = next(color_cycle), width=0)
    eggs.append(new_egg)
    root.after(egg_interval, create_egg)

def move_eggs():
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        c.move(egg, 0, 10)
        if egg_y2 > canvas_height:
            egg_dropped(egg)
    root.after(egg_speed, move_eggs)

def egg_dropped(egg):
    eggs.remove(egg)
    lose_a_life()
    if lives_remaining == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Game Over!", "Final Score: " + str(score))
        root.destroy()

def lose_a_life():
    global lives_remaining
    lives_remaining -= 1
    c.itemconfigure(lives_text, text = "Lives: " + str(lives_remaining))

def check_catch():
    (catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2, catcher_y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    for egg in eggs:
        (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
        if catcher_x < egg_x and egg_x2 < catcher_x2 and catcher_y2 - egg_y2 - egg_y2 < 40:
            eggs.remove(egg)
            c.delete(egg)
            increase_score(egg_score)
    root.after(100, check_catch)
    

def increase_score(points):
    global score, egg_speed, egg_interval
    score += points
    egg_speed = int(egg_speed * difficulty_factor)
    egg_interval = int(egg_interval * difficulty_factor)
    c.itemconfigure(score_text, text="Score: " + str(score))

def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x1 > 0:
        c.move(catcher, -20, 0)

def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x2 < canvas_width:
        c.move(catcher, 20, 0)

c.bind("<Left>" , move_left)
c.bind("<Right>" , move_right)
c.focus_set()

root.after(1000, create_egg)
root.after(1000, move_eggs)
root.after(1000, check_catch)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Error where? Which function?

Comment: it just says there is a canvas error or something

Comment: Any error happens at a line. Which line is it? Post the whole error message.

Comment: here is the full error paragraph:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SDC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\SDC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\SDC\Documents\python projects\catch the egg.py", line 50, in move_eggs
    (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)
  File "C:\Users\SDC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",

Comment: line 2766, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
(second part)

Comment: This is the valuable info:  line 50, in move_eggs (egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2) = c.coords(egg)

Comment: yes that is the exact part that is not working when the egg touches the basket it doesn't register and i lose with game instantly it would be really appreciated if you could help

Comment: I think the error happens, because it tries to check the egg coordinates one time after the window closed.

Comment: The error and the catching part not working are two different things

Comment: so what should i do to make it work if you have any idea?

Comment: oh i see what you mean so i have 2 different errors?

Comment: Yeah, the error after closing the window is expected, it has nothing to do with the eggs not being catched. So try to edit your catching logic

Comment: i don't understand what should i change to catch the eggs then?

Comment: I posted an answer you can take a look at. Next time be sure to post the whole error message right away :)

Comment: I like your game! It's impressive it works! How long did you build it?

Comment: it took about 4 hrs to think about what i wanted to call the variables and catch the other bugs :)

Comment: Thank You so much now it finally works the only issue now is that it keeps repeating the co-ordinates of the basket. I know it isn't much of an issue but it would be appreciated if you have any idea

Comment: Oh never mind i just needed to delete the part where you said  print(c.coords(egg)) and it now works fine its just the error left

Comment: mark it as accepted then. But man 4 hours is quick for a beginner. I thought this was like 2-3 days :)

Comment: so do i click the green check mark next to your answer to close it?

Comment: Yes, that's it! You nailed it

Comment: Once again, Thank you so much for helping me I don't know i would do without you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way it checks for hits and it works now.

```
def check_catch():
    catcher_x, catcher_y, catcher_x2, catcher_y2 = c.coords(catcher)
    for egg in eggs:
        egg_x, egg_y, egg_x2, egg_y2 = c.coords(egg)
        print(c.coords(egg))
        if egg_x<catcher_x<egg_x2 and (catcher_y2 - egg_y2) < 5:
            eggs.remove(egg)
            c.delete(egg)
            increase_score(egg_score)
    root.after(100, check_catch)
```